# Program executes differently when running as systemctl service

Tags: php, c, pthreads, systemctl

I have a PHP script that takes a lot of time to complete (> 1s). I want to execute one script per second, no matter if the previous one has finished running or not. 
For this, i created a C program with pthread like this :

```
void *start_instance(void *_args)
{
    int id = abs(pthread_self());
    arg_for_script* args = _args ;

    printf("[SERVICE] start php script on thread %d\n",id);

    char cmd[200] ;

    sprintf(cmd, "php -f %s %d", args->script_path, id );

    system(cmd);

    printf("[SERVICE] end of script on thread %d\n", id);
    /* Pour enlever le warning */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[SERVICE] Path of php script must be filled\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    arg_for_script args ;
    args.script_path = argv[1];

    pthread_attr_t tattr ;
    pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
    pthread_attr_getinheritsched(&tattr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(&tattr, SCHED_RR);

    while(1) {
        pthread_t thrd;


        if(pthread_create(&thrd, &tattr, start_instance, (void *)&args) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "[SERVICE] Unable to create thread\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        sleep(1);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&tattr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

if I execute this program from command line :

```
./this_program path_of_php_script_as_argv.php
```

It execute as excepted, I have an output like this :

```
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 209983744
209983744 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
209983744 | No new notification
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 209983744
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 218376448
218376448 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
218376448 | No new notification
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 218376448
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 226769152
226769152 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
226769152 | No new notification
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 226769152
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 235161856
235161856 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
235161856 | No new notification
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 235161856
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 243554560
243554560 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
243554560 | No new notification
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 243554560
```

Now, i transformed this program into a systemctl service to execute it all the time in the background, but when I `journalctl --follow` (to see systemctl output), here is what I obtain :

```
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 532399872
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 532399872
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 521811712
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 521811712
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 513419008
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 513419008
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 505026304
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 505026304
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 496633600
// ..... ~100 times, in the same second ! 
// then, second per second : 
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: [SE83728128 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:05 vps559055 start[6116]: 83728128 | No new notification
Jun 04 15:12:06 vps559055 start[6116]: 75335424 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:06 vps559055 start[6116]: 75335424 | No new notification
Jun 04 15:12:07 vps559055 start[6116]: 66942720 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:07 vps559055 start[6116]: 66942720 | No new notification
Jun 04 15:12:08 vps559055 start[6116]: 58550016 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:08 vps559055 start[6116]: 58550016 | No new notification
Jun 04 15:12:09 vps559055 start[6116]: 50157312 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:09 vps559055 start[6116]: 50157312 | No new notification
Jun 04 15:12:10 vps559055 start[6116]: 41764608 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..
Jun 04 15:12:10 vps559055 start[6116]: 41764608 | No new notification
```

all the C thread are executed the same time (same second on the logs), but the php scripts are executed second per second. Do you know why execution of these program are different ?

EDIT : Reproductible exemple : 
Create a php script script.php which contain :

```
$thid = $argv[1]?:null;
echo "php : START PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID $thid\n";
for($i = 0; $i < 3000000; $i++); // work .. 
echo "php : END PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID $thid\n";

exit ;
```

Create a main.c file containing the code above, and compile it :

```
gcc main.c -o start -lpthread
```

When you run `./start` everything is outputted as excepted :

```
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 861141248
php : START PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 861141248
php : END PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 861141248
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 861141248
[SERVICE] start php script on thread 939526400
php : START PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 939526400
php : END PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 939526400
[SERVICE] end of script on thread 939526400
```

now create a systemd service using this configuration file :

```
Description=My Service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/c/program /path/to/php/script
Restart=on-failure

# Configures the time to wait before service is stopped forcefully.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output should be what I obtain :

```
Jun 05 13:03:00 vps559055 start[4491]: php : START PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 1259825408
Jun 05 13:03:00 vps559055 start[4491]: php : END PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 1259825408
// about one second later 
Jun 05 13:03:01 vps559055 start[4491]: php : START PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 1268218112
Jun 05 13:03:01 vps559055 start[4491]: php : END PHP SCRIPT ON THREADID 1268218112
// ...
// same about 50 times 
// ...
// then suddenly, i got : 
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 1175898368
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 1175898368
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 1184291072
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 1184291072
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] start php script on thread 1192683776
Jun 05 13:03:32 vps559055 start[4491]: [SERVICE] end of script on thread 1192683776
//...
// again about 50 times, IN THE SAME SECOND, all this output 
// ...
```

Why output get so disordered when the program is executed as a systemd background service ? ...

Comment: maybe sleep using microseconds instead seconds :)

Comment: Do the first set of log outputs all appear immediately after starting the program?  Or could it be that they are delayed for, say, 100 seconds or longer?

Comment: In any case, when you say "i transformed this program into a systemctl service", I think you're saying that the code you've presented is *not* the code for a program that actually exhibited the problem for you.  If so, then that really won't do.  To answer questions about program misbehaviors we expect and typically *need* a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Bodo no absolute path for php script, but php program is called because I have in the log « start : retrieving notifications » which is output of php script. The problem here is that my thread are being called 100 times in the same second, while I put a « sleep(1) » after each thread creation. Maybe it is due to systemd service config file ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok i will try to add a mre to enable you to reproduce it

Comment: @JeremLachkar Maybe some buffering is involved. It is not clear that all `[SERVICE]` messages have been printed in the same second. See `[SE83728128 | START : Retrieving all new notifications..` which is probably `[SERVICE] start php script on thread ...` (or `...stop php...` interlaced with output from your PHP script. Try `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf` and `fflush(stderr);` after every `fprintf(stderr,...)`

Comment: @JohnBollinger I just added the minimal reproductible exemple with a sample long php script

Comment: @Bodo Thank you!! That was that, but I don't understand at all why this solution works. Why stdout buffer get sent to screen "normally", after each printf, when executing ./start and why, when I run it as systemd service, stdout get flushed so randomly ?

Comment: @JeremLachkar see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c/dvRKt-iuO40/qtYVQ6eGBNMJ "Unix convention is that stdin and stdout are line-buffered when associated with a terminal, and fully-buffered (aka block-buffered) otherwise. stderr is always unbuffered." (That means you don't need `fflush(stderr)`, but it shouldn't hurt.)

Comment: Thanks I learned something today haha:)